# How to interpret the definition of injectivity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

I am reading Terence Tao's *Analysis*. In section 3.3, he introduces the definition of injectivity as:

> A function f is one-to-one
> (or injective) if different elements map to different elements:
> $$x \neq x' \Longrightarrow f(x) \neq f(x') $$
> Equivalently, a function is one-to-one if
> $$ f(x) = f(x') \Longrightarrow x = x'$$

The language is not hard to understand. When I was doing the Exercise 3.3.3, however, I found that it is not very rigorous and different interpretations for the definition result in different conclusions.

For example, if we interpret it as (Suppose the domain is $X$)
$$ \forall x \forall x'(x \in X \wedge x' \in X \wedge (x \neq x' \Longrightarrow f(x) \neq f(x')))$$,
then the empty function is not injective since $x \in \varnothing$ is always a false statement.

On the other hand, if we interpret it as
$$\forall x \forall x'((x \in X \wedge x' \in X \wedge x \neq x') \Longrightarrow (f(x) \neq f(x'))) $$,
or
$$ \forall x \forall x'((x \in X \wedge x' \in X) \Longrightarrow( x \neq x' \Rightarrow (f(x) \neq f(x'))) $$,
then the empty function is always injective for
$$(x \in \varnothing \wedge x' \in \varnothing \wedge x \neq x') \Longrightarrow (f(x) \neq f(x'))$$
and
$$(x \in \varnothing \wedge x' \in \varnothing) \Longrightarrow( x \neq x' \Rightarrow (f(x) \neq f(x'))$$
are vacuously true.

**Which of the interpretations is right, or can there be different interpretations for a definition?**

Comment: Your second interpretation is correct. The empty function should definitely be injective.

Comment: The first interpretation is definitely incorrect, since it asserts that every object is in $X$ before it even starts talking about the function $f$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! Then can I use either interpretation 2 or 3? And more generally, to  define a property $P(f,x)$ for functions, is it always in the form $\forall x((x \in X) \Longrightarrow P(f,x))$?

Comment: Interpretations 2 and 3 are the same, yes, because $P\implies(Q\implies R)$ is logically equivalent to $(P\land Q)\implies R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation, $$\forall x\forall x'(x\in X\land x'\in X\land (x\neq x'\to f(x)\neq f(x'))),$$
is incorrect.

What you're trying to do here is to bind the universal quantifier, namely, $$(\forall x\in X)(\forall x'\in X)(x\neq x'\to f(x)\neq f(x')),$$
But a bounded universal quantifier is defined like this: $$(\forall x\in X)\varphi := \forall x(x\in X\to\varphi).$$

The correct interpretation would be the second one indeed, which is $$\forall x\forall x'((x\in X)\to((x'\in X)\to(x\neq x'\to f(x)\neq f(x')))),$$
or after simplifications, $$\forall x\forall x'((x\in X\land x'\in X)\to(x\neq x'\to f(x)\neq f(x'))).$$

Let me just add that in contrast, $(\exists x\in X)\varphi$ is defined as $\exists x(x\in X\land\varphi)$. Which is why you ended up with a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ comes with a domain $X$, then injectivity should be interpreted (in line with your second interpretation):

$$\forall x,x': \left( x \in X \land x' \in X \land x \neq x' \right) \implies (f(x) \neq f(x')$$

which indeed makes any function on an empty domain vacuously injective. The one you mention after, that has two implications, is logically equivalent, as Greg also noted in the comments $p \to (q \to r)$ is logically equivalent to $(p\land q) \to r$.